# using XSL to create XHTML from XML - a table with predefined width

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

Imagine the below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>
<book>
  <title lang="eng">A book</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>
<book>
  <title lang="eng">Another Book</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

I need to create an XSL stylesheet that displays this XML file in XHTML with only 2 books per row. The number of books in the XML file could change at any time so the XSL needs to be able take this into account. I've thought one solution of this would be to put the data into a table, however I can't rack my brains enough to figure a valid way of creating this. Possible ideas were to perform a modulus 2 check or divide total books by 2, but still unable to conclude how this might be written to create valid code. Below is my intial solution to display all books one after the other in one long column.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theStyle.css" />
        </head>
        <body onload="parent.alertsize(document.body.scrollHeight);">

            <div>

                <!--  <p><xsl:value-of select="count(//book)"/></p>-->
                <xsl:for-each select="/bookstore/book">


                        <h4><xsl:value-of select='title' /></h4>
                        <p><xsl:value-of select='price' /></p>


                    <!--<xsl:if test="postion() mod 2 = 0">
                        <p>a mod 0</p>
                    </xsl:if>-->
                </xsl:for-each>

            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Any tips/pointers/solution greatly appreciated. (Doesn't necessarily require table as solution, I just thought this might be one option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theStyle.css" />
      </head>
      <body onload="parent.alertsize(document.body.scrollHeight);">
        <div>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="bookstore/book"/>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="book[position() mod 2 = 1]">
    <h4>
      <xsl:value-of select='title' />
    </h4>
    <p>
      <p>a mod 1</p>
      <xsl:value-of select='price' />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="book[position() mod 2 = 0]">
    <h4>
      <xsl:value-of select='title' />
    </h4>
    <p>
      <p>a mod 0</p>
      <xsl:value-of select='price' />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theStyle.css">
  </head>
  <body onload="parent.alertsize(document.body.scrollHeight);">
    <div>
      <h4>Harry Potter</h4>
      <p>
        <p>a mod 1</p>29.99</p>
      <h4>Learning XML</h4>
      <p>
        <p>a mod 0</p>39.95</p>
      <h4>A book</h4>
      <p>
        <p>a mod 1</p>39.95</p>
      <h4>Another Book</h4>
      <p>
        <p>a mod 0</p>39.95</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Explanation**

You could use a loop and `xsl:if` to achieve the same result but templates are much more powerful. You can think of them as functions only applied to a matched argument. It definitely helps to reduce the indentation of your code and separate the templates for odd and even books from each other.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, I feel as though I understand templates a little better now wondered if this was also a solution.

My resulting code however, is going to get placed in an iframe, and I need to be able to use the XSL to display the elements with only 2 to each line.

I know the width of the iframe, so as a work around could I add some spacing? Or can anybody think of another solution?? You can see with your resulting code still, that they will be displayed one after the other.

Comment: @neilfoxholes Well, I thought your question was about XSL transformation, the target HTML is quite a different matter. Have a look at one of the tutorials about two column layouts (http://mirificampress.com/show.php?id=106 is not a bad one) and see if that'll work for you.